# managing content thorugh an API and directly from a file system

Tags: java, api, rest, version-control, content-management-system

For an enterprise application framework im working on right now, im looking for a way to manage assets cleverly and simply from a developers perspective.
Essentially, the scenario is one of applications metadata information being persisted on a relational database (ie: the name of the application, the different pages, the roles for that application, etc), accessed through a REST API (in example, if i want to access to full application "x" metadata, i can navigate to /applications/x and get the representation of that application in terms of pages and components of each page).

There is no code except by what we call "components" (you may think of them as bundles of reusable css+js+html).
Now, the question is: I have metadata of components on database (in example, component id, component description, etc) but also components code is on a file system under a versioned control system (SVN in our case). Meaning that the component information is both on DB and file system. 
So, if in example, some developer creates a component (that is, commits code to a particular folder where components are persisted on file system) i need to let the database know that there is a new component, and so it should be updated.
On the other hand, if the API is used to remove a particular component (something like DELETE /components/componentId1) that would remove code on file system also.

Someone would argue that code could be added as a blob to DB, but i still want to use a versioning system like SVN or GIT, so that is not an option. Also, working with code that is on a file system is much more simpler that code on a database.

So, my question is if you can provide me with some ideas, approaches, etc. to know how could be implemented a solution for managing these kind of assets that lives both on a database and on a file system, and should be consumed / modified / created both from a file system and a REST api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirements are to manage the resources from both file system and REST api then the first thing that comes to mind is that those two systems should communicate in some way.

To let your REST api know that the file system changed, first I would examine what possiblities the versioning system has to post events when certain things happen (i.e. files committed). For example it seems that Subversion supports [hooks](http://blogs.wandisco.com/2011/11/10/an-introduction-to-subversion-hook-scripts-on-windows/) that could run a java utility that would contact your REST api.

For the other side of communication (the REST api notifies the file system) you would probably need to use the API of the versioning system so when a user makes an action in your application to perform the corresponding action to the file system. Here you may have more options since all versioning systems have APIs to allow integration with IDE environments e.g. Subversion for Eclipse plugin or another possibility that comes up by google is [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/)

I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. I was indeed investigating SVNKit and hooks right now. But this approach is the most expensive from a development time perspective. I was wondering if there is something like a CMS, but without all the typical features included in them, just something to achieve the goals specified. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, seems to confirm that hard way is the only way :)